# optional dependencies within a class

Tags: php, class, oop, curl

I'm looking for some direction regarding the following, I'm new to OOP and getting there but think either my lack of understanding is causing me to get stuck in a rabbit hole or I'm just over thinking things too much and being anal.

basically i have a main class called "CurlRequest" which sole purpose is to perform curl requests, providing a url and params it returns me some html. This class works and functions as intended and I'm happy with that.

I use this class for a few projects but for one I then wanted to track the performance of my requests made. attempted, failed, passed etc, so i created a static class for this which manages all my counters. I place counter references like the following at different areas in my CurlRequest class.

```
PerformanceTracker::Increment('CurlRequest.Attempted');
PerformanceTracker::Increment('CurlRequest.Passed');
PerformanceTracker::Increment('CurlRequest.Failed');
```

I have around 10 or so of these with my class tracking all kinds of things during the curl request and i also use my PerformanceTracker class in other classes i made.

However like mentioned i only wanted to do this for one of my projects, so find my self in the situation of having my original CurlRequest class and an altered one with performance counters in it.

My question is, is their a way i can use the same class for any project and choose to use the PerformanceTracker class or not. The obvious way i thought of was to pass an $option argument into the class and then have if statements around all the counters, but can't help think its messy.

```
            if ($this->options['perfCounter'] == true ) {

                PerformanceTracker::Increment($this->owner . '.CurlRequest.Failed');

            }
```

this also adds a lot of extra code to the class.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest placing the if statement in a separate method

```
private function handlePerformanceTracker($q) 
{
    if ($this->options['perfCounter'] == true ) {

        PerformanceTracker::Increment($q);

    }
}
```

And call this method instead of your calls to

```
PerformanceTracker::Increment(...);
```

Also if you find that you want to track performance differently between your projects it might be useful to change your constructor to accept a callable argument, this way you externalize the actual implementation from the CurlRequest class itself.

```
public function __construct(..., callable performanceHandler)
```

Then when you instantiate your class:

```
$curlRequest = new CurlRequest(..., function($outcome) {
    //your implementation
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use inheritance and create a subclass that performs the logging before delegating to the parents methods:

```
class PerformanceTracker
{
    static function Increment($s)
    {
        echo $s;
    }
}

class CurlRequest
{
    function get($url){


        //preform curl request, save html to variable etc
        //dummy vars used here so working example code
        $html = 'html here';
        $curlError = false;
        if($curlError){
            $this->error($curlError);
        }


        return $this->success($html);
    }
    protected function success($html)
    {
        return $html;
    }

    protected function error($curlError)
    {
        throw new Exception($curlError);
    }

}

class LoggingCurlRequest extends CurlRequest
{


    function get($url)
    {
        PerformanceTracker::Increment('CurlRequest.Attempted');
        return parent::get($url);
    }

    function success($html)
    {
        PerformanceTracker::Increment('CurlRequest.Passed');
        return parent::success($html);
    }

    function error($curlError)
    {
        PerformanceTracker::Increment('CurlRequest.Failed');
        parent::error($curlError);
    }
}



$lcr = new LoggingCurlRequest();

$lcr->get('unused in example');
```

As i have used dummy classes with minimal code to demo the technique the benefit might not be obvious, but in you real code, the methods in the CurlRequest class will be more complex, but the methods in the logging class will remain as two liners, with the log function and the call to the parent method.

Using this technique you can modify the parent class without effecting the derived classes (provided the method signatures dont change), can create other derived classes (how about a CachingCurlRequest) etc.

For the full benefits of OOP you should look into dependency injection and interfaces

Answer (score 0):

From an OOP perspective you could use the ['Null' object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern).  This just means that the dependency used by the CurlRequest class is abstract (possibly an interface?).  You would then have Two concrete implementations of PerformanceTracker: the one you have today and one that does nothing (it does not have any behavior).  In this way for the one project when you instantiate the CurlRequest class it would use the concrete implementation that has behavior and for all the other projects it would use the concrete implementation with no behavior.  All of the code in CurlRequest would look the same but it would have different behavior depending on which concrete implementation it was using